# Input name change in two different forms causing name undefing errors

Tags: php, html, forms

I have error which I can not solve. I have two forms with submit buttons:

```
<form name="form_1"  action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;?>>
    <input type="text" name="search_1" value="<?php echo $_GET['search'] ; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Search by Name">
    </form>

<form name="form_2"  action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;?>>
    <input type="text" name="search_2" value="<?php echo $_GET['search'] ; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Search by Message">
    </form>
```

The error says that: search_1 is undefined. How can it be undefined?
Btw if I make both form input names same : `search` everything works, but as normal if I put value in one form, get the same input in other form aswell.
What I am doing wrong?

php code for form_1:

```
    <?php


    // Check if the form has been sent or if the page was accessed using the GET method.
  if( filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, "REQUEST_METHOD" ) !== "GET" ) {
    die();
  }

  $search = filter_input( INPUT_GET, "search" );

  //  Check if the searh input has been correctly fill
  if( !isset( $search ) ) {
    die();
  }
  // Let's return here to prevent open an empty file
  if( filesize( $file ) <= 0 ) {
    return;
  }

  $openedFile = fopen( $file, "r" );

  // I was using the here document option, echo <<<END END; but it didn't work due to my text editor...
  echo "
  <table width=50% border=1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Nick</th>
        <th>Message</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  ";

  // Let's save in buffer the current line and then navigate through all of them

  while( ( $buffer = fgets( $openedFile, 4096 ) ) !== false ) {


  $part = explode( "|", $buffer );
    // Here we check if the line has the searched word
    if( strpos( $part[0], $search ) !== false && $search != '') {

      echo "
          <tr>
            <td>" . $part[0] . "</td>
            <td>" . $part[1] . "</td>
            <td>" . $part[2] . "</td>
          </tr>
      ";

    }//.if
  }//.while

  echo "
    </tbody>
  </table>
  ";
?>
```

Comment: A submit button inside an html form only submits _that_ form, not the other one.

Comment: Can you show the php code snippet?

Comment: @PartharajDeb This has nothing to do with php...

Comment: But if I click submit button, it change the value of other text field

Comment: can you show us the part where you use the search_1?

Comment: Then when it shows that error message?

Comment: @PartharajDeb It show this error, when forms looks same like this. Also, that error is inside text field.

Comment: I think I understood your problem. Check back to my answer.

Comment: @KristjanKica added php code for form_1. It's almoust same as form_2

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the value from `$_GET` array without checking, is that passed in the URL or not.

Look, when you submit the first form which contains name `search_1`, at that time `search_2` must not be set in the `$_GET` array but you are printing that in the input without checking. So when you submit one form it provides error in another form.

Try like this-

```
<form name="form_1"  action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;?>>
    <input type="text" name="search_1" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['search_1'])?$_GET['search_1']:"" ; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Search by Name">
</form>

<form name="form_2"  action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;?>>
    <input type="text" name="search_2" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['search_2'])?$_GET['search_2']:"" ; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Search by Message">
</form>
```

Comment: There is no error now, but if I click on second form submit button. That second form and all content which is before form_1 are missing. I mean disappear.

Comment: Maybe it is wrong, that I use same php variable in both form, but one is for seach_1 and other for search_2?

Comment: It's a basic concept that when you submit a form any field from another form will not be submitted. If you need that I prefer you to use single form with two input with `search_1` and `search_2`.

Comment: I don't need that. Now my form 2 isn't working at all... Maybe something wrong with my php?